# Go back and call web service using params stored in localStorage AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a directive that is going to go back a page to my search document form and call my 'documentSearch' method. I'm not sure what is going wrong here as browser complains

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dsSvc' of undefined

APPCONFIG.dsSvc stores information where the web service is stored. It works absolutely fine from search page but in this directive I'm creating doesn't. Any idea why? I'm stuck on this for long enough. I'm not entirely sure if it's going to work the way I do it (go back a screen and call the web service).

```
app.directive('previousPage', ['$window', function($window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, $scope,GenericServiceSvc,APPCONFIG) {
            elem.bind('click', function () {
                $window.history.back();

                var paramsBack = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('srchParams'));

                var svcData = {
                    invoke: 'documentSearch',
                    app: APPCONFIG.dsSvc,
                    params: paramsBack
                };

                GenericServiceSvc.callService(svcData).then(

                    function (response) {
                        if (response) {
                            console.log(response);
                        } else {
                            //no results
                        }
                    }, function () {
                        console.log(svcData.invoke + '- Fail');
                    }
                );

            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The link function has the following signature:

`function link(scope, element, attrs, controller, transcludeFn) {...}`

It looks like you're trying to inject APPCONFIG (is it a service/factory/constant?) into the link function, so what you're really asking is for AngularJS to get dsSvc from what it expects to be the `transcludeFn` argument.

Move your injections to the directive function:

```
app.directive('previousPage', ['$window', 'GenericServiceSvc', 'APPCONFIG', function($window, GenericServiceSvc, APPCONFIG) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.bind('click', function () {
                $window.history.back();

                var paramsBack = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('srchParams'));

                var svcData = {
                    invoke: 'documentSearch',
                    app: APPCONFIG.dsSvc,
                    params: paramsBack
                };

                GenericServiceSvc.callService(svcData).then(

                    function (response) {
                        if (response) {
                            console.log(response);
                        } else {
                            //no results
                        }
                    }, function () {
                        console.log(svcData.invoke + '- Fail');
                    }
                );

            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: APPCONFIG is indeed a factory. I'm never too sure how to structure those directives. I've spent some time going through some documentation but it just wasn't explained in a way I could understand. I'll see how it goes with your version and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: It has worked but the outcome is close to expected. I can now view the documents by using 'console.log(respose);' but they are not displayed as from the search page because many variables are defined in the controller and this directive is stored in app.js file. I've copied most of the search() function that is responsible for searching documents. Even when I'm using $scope.sortBy for example, browser complains with this error: 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'sortBy' of undefined'. I don't want to copy and paste all the functions I have defined in my controller so the directive could work...

Comment: You can `require` a directive controller, or access it through `scope`.  Brush up on the documentation, what you're asking doesn't require you to move all your functions around.